# Incrustrar pagina de superset en un iframe

Tags: reactjs

tengo el siguiente problema, estoy tratando de usar un tablero de superset en mi aplicación de react, con el siguiente enlace, como lo sugieren varias paginas es cambiando el config.py, e decidido consultar por mi cuenta ya que e intentado de miles de formas pero no logro nada, la idea mia es que se salte el login y aparezca simplemente el tablero que yo quiera pone, les dejo un ejemplo en la parte inferior.

http://localhost:8088/superset/dashboard/births/?standalone=true

tambien les dejo el enlace como instale superset en docker
https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-using-docker-compose/